# pdfTeX hang prevention

Tags: errors

I am faced with pdfTex hanging problem and and looking for a workaround if exists. For example, I know that the following formula expression is  mistyped, but I dont know why pdfTex is frozen(possibly infinite loop) instead of quting nicely? Is there a workaround? Because in case of an erronous input, I don't want to restart my server.
edit: as comments suggest, problem is clarified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\SetWatermarkText{FAST MATH}
\SetWatermarkScale{2}
\SetWatermarkVerCenter{0.6\paperheight}
\SetWatermarkAngle{30}

\begin{document}

\section{Input}
$\left. \begin{array} { l } { a ) A = \{ 2   $
\section{Solution}
${a: 0}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try running pdflatex with the `-halt-on-error` commandline option.

Comment: What do you mean with frozen? Usually it should prompt and wait for input (you will see an asterisk `*` on that line). That is to avoid redoing all compilation, but provide a way to "inline edit" the error. The alternative: fix all errors…

Comment: you can't avoid all loops, setup your server so that it times out if necessary.

Comment: @TeXnician I am calling pdfTex from a python app with "--interaction=batchmode" flag. As a frozen, I mean it enters to infinite loop(consumes most of the cpu - hard to kill) .

Comment: @heral In general that is a problem with batchmode, there are errors where this is just not going to avoid anything. You may, however, check for TeX waiting for input and then simply pass an "x" to the prompt…

Comment: @ Eric Marsden your suggestion seems to work me while @TeXnican's suggestion is also feasable. Thanks. Btw, I dont know if I can thick a comment as solution?

Comment: It seems, in your comments here and to other answers, that your question has more to do with how to handle a condition where a program you're creating/writing has problems when pdflatex hangs due to invalid input; rather than asking what is wrong with the sample input.  If so ... you might want to edit this question and its title appropriately to describe what you're really trying to ask.  And it may even be the case that this is more appropriately handled elsewhere on Stack Exchange, for example, at Stack Overflow.

Comment: You might be interested in [Using module 'subprocess' with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374) to timeout a process called from python. If you're allowing arbitrary unchecked code in your document, I hope you have your TeX installation set up with the highest security settings.

Comment: @heral it is provably impossible in any non trivial programming language to avoid or detect all loops. This is the "Turing halting problem", the halt on error suggestion will stop tex if there is an error but it is easy to make tex loop in non-error cases, `\def\foo{\foo}\foo` for example.

Comment: @David Carlisle, you have a point but a program can be avoid loops in many circumstances, there are workaround and some is embedded in the binaries; like, setting a watchdog or monitoring cpu usage. Your point is theoratical I think.

Comment: not theoretical at all. The definition I give above will loop forever without using any stack and require the tex process to be killed externally. under one of the answers you commented "what I need is frozen free pdfTex" that is not possible, you need to use an additional process that kills the tex job if it runs for too long.

Comment: @David Carlisle, if you make an app multithreaded, and set a thread for watchdog stuff, then your app never hangs in practice?

Comment: that comes to the same thing. The sources of the tex binary are essentially frozen so if you want to have tex processing  in one thread and interrupted by another you need to write (or use) an application that does that. teX itself will not help.

Comment: @EricMarsden, please rewrite your comment as an seperate answer so that I can accept it. It was  the thing that really worked. And thanks to other guys, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run pdflatex with the `-halt-on-error` commandline option, it won't enter the debugger on error. That is generally much more convenient for "batch mode" use of LaTeX.

Answer (score 15):

The issue can be reproduced with a smaller example, showing it has nothing to do with the loaded packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\left. \begin{array} { l } { a ) A = \{ 2   $

\section{Solution}
${a: 0}$

\end{document}
```

The errors in the math formula, followed by the section title, make TeX enter an infinite loop announced by

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{array} on input line 7 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.12 \end{document}

? 

! Improper \prevdepth.
\newpage ...everypar {}\fi \par \ifdim \prevdepth 
                                                  >\z@ \vskip -\ifdim \prevd...
l.12 \end{document}
```

The missing `\end{array}` causes `\par` to still be defined as “do nothing” like it always is in `array`. Since the error recovery here is to try doing `\end{document}`, LaTeX tries to finish up the page issuing `\par`, which does nothing.

If we add `\tracingmacros=1`, after the last error message we see, in the log file after interrupting the program, a string of

```
\par ->

\par ->

\par ->

\par ->

\par ->
```

Solution: don't make silly errors in your input.

Another solution could be running `pdflatex` with the option `-halt-on-error`, which would stop it at the first error.

However, this is not foolproof. If the user has `\def\foo{\foo}` in their preamble, then the first usage of `\foo` in the document would start an infinite loop with *no* error.

Comment: "Solution: don't make silly errors in your input." unfortuntely this is unavoidable as I explained.

Answer (score 5):

This is an answer to the actual problem of running TeX as a subprocess on a document that contains user supplied code that you have no control over (rather than focusing on the particular example you've provided).

As already mentioned by others, it's trivially easy to trigger an infinite loop in TeX without generating any errors. Your example shows a plausible user mistake (forgetting the end of an environment) but you also need to guard against a malicious user deliberately triggering an infinite loop.

Whenever you have an application or script that spawns a subprocess that has the potential to run indefinitely it's a good idea to include a timeout. Since you're using Python, you might find the answers to [Using module 'subprocess' with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374) useful.

There are, however, other types of malicious code that you need to consider. There were some significant improvements made in both TeX Live and MikTeX in 2010 to improve security, but there have also been some more recent fixes, such as:

- [Buffer overflow in `texlive-bin` allowed arbitrary code execution when a malicious Type 1 font is loaded.](https://www.debian.org/security/2018/dsa-4299)
- [Incorrect handling of certain files in TeX Live on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://usn.ubuntu.com/3788-1/)

So make sure you have an up-to-date TeX distribution.

The security settings for TeX Live are in the `texmf.cnf` configuration file. There are two of these files by default and their locations can be found with `kpsewhich -a texmf.cnf`. One contains the default settings that shouldn't be modified. The other can be used to override specific settings if required.

The security settings for MikTeX are in the [`miktex.ini` file](https://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/defaults.html).

The main source for concern is the shell escape (`\write18`). There are three modes:

- Disabled (`shell_escape=f` in the `texmf.cnf` file or use `-no-shell-escape` when running TeX). This will prevent any systems commands from being called by TeX. This is the most secure mode.
- Restricted (`shell_escape=p` in the `texmf.cnf` file). This imposes the following restrictions on `\write18`:

  - Certain characters are forbidden (such as `'` and `;`) to prevent injection.
  - Only applications on the trusted list can be run. These are identified in the `shell_escape_commands` setting in the `texmf.cnf` file. You can list them with `kpsewhich -var-value=shell_escape_commands` There are currently eight: `bibtex`, `bibtex8`, `extractbb`, `gregorio`, `kpsewhich`, `makeindex`, `repstopdf`, `texosquery-jre8`. These have been evaluated by the TeX Live security team and determined to be safe. (It is, however, possible to still misuse this setting with destructive effect, as I recently demonstrated in the UK TUG meeting.)
- Unrestricted (`shell_escape=t` in the `texmf.cnf` file or use `-shell-escape` when running TeX). This allows any system command to be called and is therefore insecure.

Another area of concern are the file I/O operations, which are essential to common document build requirements (such as generating table of contents, cross-referencing and indexes) but can be misused. In addition to the operating system's native file permissions, TeX also has settings to determine whether read or write access is allowed.

The `texmf.cnf` file has two settings `openin_any` and `openout_any` that may take one of the following values:

- `a`: any file allowed (if permitted by the operating system);
- `r`: (restricted) hidden dot files not allowed;
- `p`: (paranoid) hidden dot files not allowed, and disallow going to parent directories (`..`) and restrict absolute paths to be under `$TEXMFOUTPUT`.

The default values are:

```
openin_any = a
openout_any = p
```

The paranoid setting prevents files from being acessed outside of the current working path (the directory that TeX was called from).

For example, suppose you are running TeX on a web server and suppose your home directory on that server is `/home/foo` and the root for your website is `/home/foo/public_html` (so, for example, if your website is `www.example.com` then `www.example.com/index.php` corresponds to the file `/home/foo/public_html/index.php`).

If you run TeX from your home directory (`/home/foo`) then, even with the paranoid setting, malicious code added to your document can overwrite `public_html/index.php` (if it's not protected by the filing system). Your website's home page is now corrupted.

With the file read operation, if the user gets to see the generated PDF, they can use malicious TeX code to access information from your system. Suppose you have a script `/home/foo/public_html/foobar.php` that accesses a database. This could be input verbatim into the document and the database connection information, including the password, can now be read from the PDF.

TeX code can be obfuscated so don't rely on using regular expressions to check for certain commands within the user-supplied code.

Summary:

- Ensure you have an up-to-date TeX installation.
- Invoke TeX with a timeout that will automatically kill the process if it goes on too long.
- Run TeX with `-no-shell-escape`.
- Run TeX in a safe directory that doesn't have any subdirectories leading to important files.
- Ensure that both `openout_any` and `openin_any` are set to `p`.
- If you need to view the generated PDF, make sure that your PDF viewer has JavaScript disabled.

Answer (score 4):

You have unbalanced environments/braces; `\begin{array}` doesn't have `\end{array}` and `\left.` doesn't have `\right..`. Also, load `breqn` after `amsmath` and add `lmodern` for preventing missing font sizes substitution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lmodern}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\SetWatermarkText{FAST MATH}
\SetWatermarkScale{2}
\SetWatermarkVerCenter{0.6\paperheight}
\SetWatermarkAngle{30}

\begin{document}

\section{Input}
$ \begin{array} { l }  a) A = \{ 2  \end{array}$
\section{Solution}
${a: 0}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know that there is unbalanced expression in the tex file(there may always be, as some part of it user input), what I need is frozen free pdfTex.